# Is a semicolon required before a function closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, compilation

I'm wondering if this is a compiler bug, or this is the way it's supposed to be.

Using node.js v10.15.3, this code throws an error:

```
var x
x = false
(function y() { console.log('foo') }())
```

But this code works fine:

```
var x
x = false;
(function y() { console.log('foo') }())
```

It's the semicolon that makes the difference.  The error message is: "TypeError: false is not a function", so it appears that without the semicolon, the compiler is parsing the open paren after the "false" keyword as a function call, as if I had written "x = false()".  It took me a long time to figure out what was going wrong in my code (which was more complex than the example above, obviously.)  That's a chunk of my life I won't get back!

My question is: why? I thought semicolons were not necessary at the end of a line?  I've just been reading the [ECMA spec on semicolon insertion](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) trying to figure this out, but it's still a little murky to me.

I guess the moral of the story is to just go ahead and terminate all lines with semicolons.  The funny thing is that, as a C programmer, that was my habit, and I was just trying to catch up with the times by dropping all those unneeded semicolons.

Comment: Check the rules of *automatic semicolon insertion* (ASI) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript parser see this

```js
var x
x = false
(function y() { console.log('foo') }())
```

as this:

```js
var x;
x = false(function y() { console.log('foo') }());
```

which means you're trying to call `false` as a function. This is because JS parser always tries to get the longest expression.

In most cases, to write JS with or without semicolons is just a matter of styling. However, you'll need to add semicolons when:

- There are 2 lines of code, and
- the first line ends with a possible identifier (or keywords, like `if` or `while`), and
- The second line starts with a bracket.

In this case the semicolon should be added to the end of the first line, or the beginning of the second line.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about false being called as a function.
Your first code block is equivalent to this:

```js
var x
x = false(function y() { console.log('foo') }())
```

As there is no semicolon separating the lines, the js interpreter *calls the keyword false, passing in the function y as an argument*. This obviously results in an error as false is not callable.

Semicolon use is almost required in this case, where an open parenthesis is the furs character on a line. A way use semicolons only when necessary is to place them before an open parenthesis, like follows:

```js
var x
x = false
;(function y(){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases line breaks doesn't matter. In the cases where the code would be right syntax without line break.

Consider the below snippet where a nested function is called with two `()` and calling is separated by one line. But it doesn't matter.

```js
function x(){
  return function(){ return 6}
}
let a =
x()

()
console.log(a) //6
```

The above line will still be evaluated as

```
let a = x()()
```

The general rule is that where ever the code makes sense and doesn't throw error without a semicolon. It doesn't insert semi color there. It only inserts semicolon when there is no other choice.