# Why doesn't this one-liner that creates an array and pushes to it work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, initialization

When I run this code, it works, as you would expect:

```
var b = {}
b['foo']=[]
b['foo'].push(1)
```

But when I try doing this as a one-liner, like this:

```
var b = {}
(b['foo']=[]).push(1)
```

It throws: `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'foo')`, even though `b` is very clearly defined.

Could someone explain this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Edit: For some reason, adding the semicolon fixes the issue, which confirms that the compiler was in fact trying to run it as a function. But now I have another question: Why did it throw an error saying `b` is not defined, instead of `b` is not a function?

Comment: Try adding a `;` at the end of your lines. Because right now it is trying to execute `{}` as a function, which obviously won't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a semicolon required before a function closure in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195773/is-a-semicolon-required-before-a-function-closure-in-javascript)

Comment: @Reyno That could be the answer, but wouldn't it throw something along the lines of `b` isn't a function if that were the case?

Comment: Reyno: If it was parsed that way, shouldn't the error message be "Uncaught TypeError: {} is not a function"?

Comment: @Daavee18 yes and no. Since `b['foo']=[]` is evaluated before `{}()` it will throw your error. Otherwise we indeed get something like *"{} is not a function"* or *"unexpected token ')'"*

Comment: @Reyno Oh, I get it now, it was trying to parse `b['foo']` as an argument. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @LMD already did a great job creating an answer, no need for duplicate answers. I got my credits, you can mark his as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Reyno, this is parsed as

```js
var b = {}(b['foo']=[]).push(1)
```

[since there is no semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195773/is-a-semicolon-required-before-a-function-closure-in-javascript) delimiting `var b = {}` and `(b['foo']=[]).push(1)`, thus the [rules of automatic semicolon insertion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion) apply. The question that remains is why this throws

> `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'foo')`

rather than

> `Uncaught TypeError: {} is not a function`

which ought to be thrown for `{}()`. The reason for this is that

```js
var b = {}(b['foo']=[]).push(1)
```

is equivalent to

```
var b; b = {}(b['foo']=[]).push(1)
```

The right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated first, so *before* the call is made, it evaluates `b['foo']` to evaluate the inner assignment, but `b` is `undefined`, leading to the error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'foo')`.

Comment: The [Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion) should be mentioned, as they explain why the new line is parsed as a function call.